# Comparing websites using selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I need to test websites using selenium webdriver on java. My goal is to make and save changes on one website and then see if the other website changed content accordingly. I want to make a change, then switch to a different window with a different website, then back and forth multiple times. Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: Yes It is possible , What you have tried?

Comment: The question was is it possible? I do not ask how to implement particular code.  So your kind answer is yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible!
And you can actually do it by switching between various windows.
Here you can find a great guide about the switch commands: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/
For example:

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle(); //save the current window handle

for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
 driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
} //switch window

driver.close(); //close the new window

driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore); //switch again to the first window
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I will go with this!